# UWP ResourceDictionary Style Error: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, resourcedictionary

I'm making a ResourceDictionary of common styles that are used throughout my application and one of them is:

```
<Style x:Key="ME_BASE_AppbarButtonSaveStyle"
       TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Label"
            Value="Save" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip"
            Value="Save" />
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                      Glyph="&#xE105;" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It's all ok if I apply the style only one AppbarButton on the Page, but if I want to have two buttons with the same style, I get the following error:

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

It's of ok (no error) if I remove the icon property out of the style...
But that's kind of missing the point...

Anyone experienced something similar? Perhaps...

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I tested your code and it works okay. Please share your ResourceDictionary and app.xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error HRESULT E_Fail has been returned from a call to a COM component.

This error will occurred when you use this style for the second `AppBarButton`. This error usually happens when a reference to a style or an event handler that does not exist or is not with the context of the XAML, you can see the exception information of your problem:
[image]

If you read this document: [XAML resources must be shareable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187273.aspx#xaml_resources_must_be_sharable), you will find:

> Custom types used as resources can't have the UIElement class in their inheritance, because a UIElement can never be shareable (it's always intended to represent exactly one UI element that exists at one position in the object graph of your runtime app).

Whether a [Icon property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton.Icon);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true) of `AppBarButton` or a [FontIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.FontIcon);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true) derives from `UIElement`, so I guess this is the reason why can't this property be styled in the resource dictionary.

Besides, I will consider if this is a right direction to define the `Icon` property for each `AppBarButton` in the style, normally I'd like give each button a different icon as content.

But if you insist to do this, I can provide you a workaround method by defining the `Content` of the `AppBarButton`, this is the construction of your `AppBarButton`:
[image]

You use a `FontIcon` as the content of the `AppBarButton`, so we can modify your style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ME_BASE_AppbarButtonSaveStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Label" Value="Save" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="Save" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
              Glyph="&#xE105;" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Awesome
It works like a charm :)
Also, thank you for thorough explanation why my way couldn't possibly work... I had no idea about this part: 'Custom types used as resources can't have the UIElement class in their inheritance'
Thank you very much